# Question On Thermal Sizing Methodology

Tags: power, mosfet, heat, thermal

I'd like to know if I am going in the right direction in my methodology for sizing a thermal solution for some power MOSFETs in a controller.

To give some background, I am switching a couple of different loads, 1 24V@100A continuous max, 4 24V@30A continuous max, and several smaller 5V loads, all using FETs physically near each other. In this controller's application, all of the loads may be max-ed at once, though this is unlikely.

Before any one asks, yes, switching them is necessary. Believe me I tried getting around it, but to no avail :( .

Any way, my methodology is as follows:

1. Group the FETs thermally under one heat sink to reduce cost and complexity, and since they are already physically near each other.
2. Calculate the total heat dumped into the shared heat sink at once.
3. Calculate the thermal resistance of the heat sink from thermal load to ambient to keep the FET with the highest junction to case thermal resistance under or at my max operating temperature.
4. Slap a margin of 20% on top of the number to build some wiggle room into the design.

Is this a good way to go about solving this problem? My background is Aerospace Engineering, so I tried to take what I learned in Thermodynamics all those years ago and actually apply it, I have no idea if heat calculations are done differently in the electronics world.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 20% isn't much margin. I'd explore what a higher margin (50%?) implies in size and cost and decide accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methodology sounds reasonable. In general I oversize power FETs as much as is reasonable so I don’t have to worry as much about problems with heat sinks.

Keep in mind that much of the heat comes from switching the FET.  Little heat is generated in the ON and OFF states; rather the heat comes while the FET is transitioning. So do what you can to have as few transitions per second. If you are doing PWM, then this usually means picking a frequency just above 20kHz so it doesn’t produce audible ringing. It also means driving the FET so it turns on/off very quickly and spends as little time as possible transitioning. There are FET drivers for this exact purpose.  Depending on your application and circuit, you may be able to avoid heat sinks all together.